# Flutter - bottomModalSheet can't validate a textfield widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have attached a project which is having a bottom modal sheet. Which sheet contains three `TextField` as name, number and email. So here I have implemented CRUD (Create, read, update and delete) operation and it's fine working. But without validating the `TextField` it shows in the `HomePage`. although if I miss to enter name or number still it's passing the data to the homepage card. I have tried many validating options but didn't worked out. If anyone can please help me.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});


  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {



  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _contacts = [];

  bool _isLoading = true;
  final bool _validatename = true;
  final bool _validatenumber = true;
  final bool _validateemail = true;
  

    void _refreshContacts() async {
      final data = await Contact.getContacts();

      setState(() {
        _contacts  = data;
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _refreshContacts();
    }


    final  _nameController = TextEditingController();
    final  _numberController = TextEditingController();
    final  _emailController = TextEditingController();

    final bool _validate = false;


    void _showForm(int? id) async {
      if (id != null) {
        final existingContact = _contacts.firstWhere((element) => element['id'] ==id);
        _nameController.text = existingContact['name'];
        _numberController.text = existingContact['number'];
        _emailController.text = existingContact['email'];
      }

    showModalBottomSheet(context: context,
    elevation: 5,
    isScrollControlled: true,
     builder: (_) => Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 15, right: 15, bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 120),

      child:  Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _nameController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Name",
              ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            controller: _numberController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Numbers",
              ),
            
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          TextField(
            // keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            controller: _emailController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Email Address",
              ),

          ),          
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),

          Row(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed:  () async {
                
                if (id == null) {
                  await _addContact();
                }

                if (id != null) {
                  await _updateContact(id);
                }




                Navigator.of(context).pop();

                _nameController.text = '';
                _numberController.text = '';
                _emailController.text = '';
              },

              
               child: Text(id == null ? 'Create New' : 'Update'),
               ),
               const SizedBox(
                width: 10.0,
               ),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async {
                _nameController.text = '';
                _numberController.text = '';
                _emailController.text = '';
              }, child: const Text("Clear")),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10.0,
               ),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);

              }, child: const Text("Go Back")),
            ],
          ),


      ]),
      
     ));
      

    }

    Future<void> _addContact() async {
      await Contact.createContact(
        _nameController.text, _numberController.text, _emailController.text
      );
      _refreshContacts();
    }

    Future<void> _updateContact(int id) async {
      await Contact.updateContact(id, _nameController.text, _numberController.text, _emailController.text );

      _refreshContacts();
    }

    void _deleteContact(int id) async {
      await Contact.deleteContact(id);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Sccessfully Contact Deleted")));
      _refreshContacts();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Contact App",),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        centerTitle: true,
        toolbarHeight: 80,
      ),
      body: _isLoading ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),) : 
      ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _contacts.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => 
          Card(
            elevation: 5,
            shape: const Border(
              right: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 10.0),
        
            ),
            color: Colors.orange[200],
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 20.0,
              shadowColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(_contacts[index]['name'], style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                subtitle: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(_contacts[index]['number'], style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18),),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 5.0,
                    ),
                    Text(_contacts[index]['email'], style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.black),),
                  ],
                ),
                trailing: SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(onPressed: () => _showForm(_contacts[index]['id']), icon: const Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.blueGrey,)),
        
                      IconButton(onPressed: () => _deleteContact(_contacts[index]['id']), icon: const Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red,)),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.add, size: 28,),
          onPressed: () => _showForm(null), 
        ),
    );
  }


}
```

Above codes are from homepage. I need only the validating part + if anyone can know how to show the each card in another page using page route. Actually this is a contact app. I have tried the new screen to show the full details but couldn't.

Comment: Cant see `validator` and Form widget

Comment: In "showModalBottomSheet" method wrap your column with a "Form" widget and provide it with formkey, then substitute "TextField" widgets with "TextFormField" widgets, then provide each one with a validator property.

Comment: tried with the textfield form too and key constructor still didnt worked out.

Comment: If you have such a big code/widgets in the bottom sheet then the best way is to do the code in the 2nd Statefull widget and just call that widget in the bottom sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can return when any of the field is empty like

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    if (_nameController.text.isEmpty ||
        _numberController.text.isEmpty ||
        _emailController.text.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
  },
  child: Text(id == null ? 'Create New' : 'Update'),
),
```

But it will be better to use Form widget TextFormFiled with validator . Find more on [validation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation)

```dart
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  elevation: 5,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (_) => Container(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter some text';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  controller: _nameController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Name",
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final isValided =
                            _formKey.currentState?.validate();

                        if (isValided == true) {}
                      },
                      child: Text(id == null ? 'Create New' : 'Update'),
                    ),
```

Comment: is that the first comment will work? and the textfield form i tried same thing . didnt worked. if can you please implement?

Comment: 1st will work but will be no visual , test both and see what suit you better. Also check the link for more.

Comment: nope didnt worked the second one. What is the value parameter inside the validator obj?? do I need to give _nameController for that or just leave with value?

Comment: that is Nullable string , make sure add all validator, but 1st will recommend to test link example

Comment: hey its worked i just noticed that when clicking the button its shows the error message but still its passing the to the screen .

Comment: put every navigation logic inside `if (isValided == true) {...}`

Comment: yeasin. Masha allah . great. it's working Im happy brother. more knowledge to you....